# flutter NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'lat' was called on null

Tags: flutter

When searching through Google Maps, a function that returns a location is used, and null is called.
The placeDetail class is initialized and used, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
void _moveCamera() async {
try{
  GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
  controller.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
        LatLng(
            placeDetail.lat,
            placeDetail.lng)),
  );
} catch(e) {
  print("error?? -$e");

}

print("noo - ${placeDetail.lat}");
print("noo - ${placeDetail.lng}");

setState(() {
  _markers.add(
      Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(placeDetail.name),
    position: LatLng(placeDetail?.lat, placeDetail.lng),
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: placeDetail.name,
        snippet: placeDetail.formattedAddress),
  ));
});
}
```

json을 받아온 부분은 문제가 없는 걸로 생각됩니다.
formatted_address: 대한민국 서울특별시 은평구 응암동, geometry: {location: {lat: 37.5942526, lng: 126.9185857}, 이렇게 출력이됩니다.

I initialized it here.

```
void getCurrentPosition() async {
LocationData pos = await location.getLocation();
setState(() {
  currentPos = LatLng(
    pos.latitude,
    pos.longitude,
  );
});


placeDetail = PlaceDetail(lng: pos.longitude, lat: pos.latitude); 
print('google mapff - ${currentPos.latitude}');


GoogleMapController mapCtrl = await _mapController.future;
mapCtrl.animateCamera(
  CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
    CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(
            currentPos.latitude,
            currentPos.longitude),
        zoom: zoomLevel),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: can you add some more code? The code you have added right now looks okay, but it seems there is an issue in the flow somewhere.

Comment: The error was caused by incorrectly adding boolean to json data. Thanks for finding a solution together!

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined placeDetail ? You have to make sure placeDetail is within the scope of the code being executed.

Comment: I have added the place you defined